# Merge two crontab entries into a single entry

Tags: linux, cron

In my crontab file I have two entries

```
00 13 * * * DISPLAY=:0.0 /home/noob/.scripts/backup.sh 
00 21 * * * DISPLAY=:0.0 /home/noob/.scripts/backup.sh
```

Now can I write a single entry which executes the `backup.sh` file @ 1:00PM and 9:00PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
00 13,21 * * * DISPLAY=:0.0 /home/noob/.scripts/backup.sh
```